# Como llamar ciertos datos de la base mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una tabla llamada sucursales la cual necesito llamar solo 2 sucursales la una es Ambato y Ficoa solo esos 2 datos quiero que se vean en un select .

```
    //Vista manda a llamar todas las sucursales
    <select class="form-control buscar" name="sucursal_id" required>
     <option value="">Seleccionar</option>                           
         <?php                                      
           $columna = null;
           $valor = null;
    
           $cliente = sucursalC::verSucursalC($columna, $valor);                                    
    
           foreach ($cliente as $key => $value) {                                      
              echo '<option value="'. $value["id"] .'">'. $value["nombre"] .'</option>';
                                   
        ?>  
    </select>
```

```
    //Controlador
static public function verSucursalC($columna, $valor) {
    
    $tabla = "sucursal";
    
    $respuesta = sucursalM::verSucursalM($tabla, $columna, $valor);
    
    return $respuesta;
    
}
```

```
    //Modelo
static public function verSucursalM($tabla, $columna, $valor) {
    
    if($columna == null){

        $pdo = conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

        $pdo -> execute();

        return $pdo ->fetchall();

    }else{

        $pdo = conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $columna = :$columna");

        $pdo -> bindParam(":".$columna, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $pdo -> execute();

        return $pdo ->fetch();

    }
}
```

Comment: Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Osea la pregunta es como llamo solo a los datos que yo requiero que son 2, Dentro de esa tabla existen 22 nombres de ciudades las cuales solo quiero llamar a la ciudad de Ambato y Ficoa? y no a toda la lista.

Comment: Y si la agregas al where de tu consulta?

Comment: ok, lo voy a intentar

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente estés buscando usar [IN](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Ayuda a evitar la construcción de una query de varios OR

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1  
WHERE column2 = 'val 1'   
   OR column2 = 'val 2'   
   OR column2 = 'val 3';
```

Se reduce a

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1  
WHERE column2 IN( 'val 1', 'val 2','val 3');
```

Comment: Lo voy a intentar, gracias